# Python and VS Code issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

VS Code terminal won't output my Python Code.

I keep getting this:

```
PS C:\Users\danie\OneDrive\Documents\Exercise Files\Ch2> cd 'c:\Users\danie\OneDrive\Documents\Exercise Files\Ch2'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:/Python/Python37/Python.exe' 'c:\Users\danie\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.5.18875\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '57829' 'c:\Users\danie\OneDrive\Documents\Exercise Files\Ch2\helloworld_start.py'
```

I've set up the launch.JSON file as follows

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",     
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

```py
def main():
    print("hello world")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I just want a print out of "hello world" but it seems I'm missing something in the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two lines, where you call the main function, were indented. This meant that they were part of the main function.

By removing the indent, those two lines will execute when you run the file and call the main function as you intended. See this

```
def main():
    print("hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```